# WordPress - Ultimate Member - allow a particular profile field edit for one role and doesn't allow for another

Tags: wordpress, field, roles, profile, ultimate-member

I'm a newcomer in the world of wordpress and ultimate member plugin and I need help of those who have more experience.
I know that it's possible to define the visibility for a profile field as for edit, view or both and I know that it's possible to define the privacy for a field for particular roles, but I fail to find a way to allow the same profile field to be editable for one role(not owner) and not editable for another role(not owner).
Ex.:
there are 3 roles: role a, role b and super role b.
role A has profile field A and profile field B.
field A is editable for both role B and role super B, while field B is editable for role super B, but not editable for role B.

I can make field B either visible and editable for roles B and super B, or not visible for both on the Edit tab.

Could you please help me?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/